# Delete vertical and horizontal lines of certain length from image using imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

[image]

I need to remove the vertical and horizontal line inside each block. For example in the top left block, I want to remove the small lines to the right and bottom of 31. I want to remove all such lines in the image. 
I tried the following:

```
convert my_image.png -negate -define morphology:compose=darken -morphology Thinning Rectangle:1x130+0+0< -negate new_image.png
```

And I am getting this error:

```
bash: -negate: No such file or directory
```

Where am I going wrong.

**UPDATE**:
This is the expected output. I did this in GIMP. Please notice that that the right and bottom lines around the top-left numbers of each block are gone.

[image]

Comment: Check for bad characters. Perhaps the - (hyphens) are short or long hyphens rather than the normal hyphen. Try replacing `1x130+0+0<` with either `1x130+0+0\<` or with `"1x130+0+0<"`

Comment: @fmw42 The code is working with `1x130+0+0\<` but am not able to remove those lines. I tried `1x130+0+0\>` too but I am getting the same image, as in the bigger column and row lines are turning into white. I just need to remove those small lines as it is causing problems in OCR. Can you help?

Comment: Where did you get this command? What makes you think it would work. Have you used it before? I have seen this question with a similar image before on this forum. Have you searched to find out if there was a solution. I think it had to do with cropping out the text from each cell.

Answer (score 0):

As test, I cropped your image to a small part and flattened against a white background. Then applied your command and it worked reasonably well.

```
convert my_image.png +repage -crop 1000x1000+0+0 +repage -background white -flatten tmp.png
```

[image]

```
convert tmp.png -negate -define morphology:compose=darken -morphology Thinning Rectangle:1x130+0+0\< -negate tmp2.png
```

[image]

Is that what you want? If not, please explain what further is needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. I need to remove the entire right and bottom lines around the numbers. Its just partially removed from your images (and also from what I tried on my computer).

Comment: I have updated the main question and added the expected output image. I used the eraser tool in GIMP, just have to do this on a large set of images.

Comment: The vertical lines should be doable with a similar command using a vertical line for the morphology. The horizontal lines are difficult since your text has longer horizontal lines and those would get remove also.